Excel IF cell column contains x value then return/charge x value
I am working on a dataset with some courier information. When a particular waybill/tracking number contains certain values a certain amount needs to be charged. tracking/waybill number can look like this
PPA656778686/PNA567765786/PCC675787/HPC8877


If the waybill contains PPA  charge must be R75
If the waybill contains PP charge must be R75
If the waybill contains PNA charge must be R100
If the waybill contains PCC charge must be R200

If it contains anything else then charge will be R250.
This is the formula i entered :
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PPA",[waybill_number])),75, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PNA",[waybill_number])),150, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PCC",[waybill_number])),200, 250)))

But it gives me R75 for all my values. How do i fix this?

Is the waybill number just one item? And you only care about the first 3 letters? If so, create a table with the different 3-char options and the charge for each. Then use LEFT([waybill_number],3) and XLOOKUP (which lets you specify a default if no matches)

Awesome, got it.
Essentially, extract the first 3 letters of the entire waybill number, then do the charging from there. This works just fine. Thank you
Now when it comes to the different pricing, do I make use of the IF statements or is there a better and more effective approach?

My preference is to do something akin to @JvdV's answer below. I don't like hard-coded numbers in formula: much better to have a separate 'charging' Table, with another cell containing the 'default' price. It makes it easier and less error-prone to maintain: eg what if you have a new code: it is much easier to add one line to a Table than it is to amend the logic in multiple formulae.

Note that PP is included in PPA and has the same price, therefor I set it out as such:

Formula in B2:
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(w,FILTER(E1:E3,COUNTIF(w,D1:D3&"*"),250)))

And if you have structured referencing, thus a table, forget about LAMBDA():
=FILTER(E1:E3,COUNTIF([waybill_number],D1:D3&"*"),250)


You could try using the following formula:


=MAP(A1:A7,LAMBDA(m,IFERROR(TOCOL(E1:E3/(LEFT(m,{2,3})=D1:D3),3),250)))


Without LAMBDA()
=IFERROR(TOCOL(E$1:E$3/(LEFT(A1,{2,3})=D$1:D$3),2),250)



You have received some nice options. If you want to keep it simple and closer to the approach that you originally planned then you can use the below as suggested by @DS_London
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="PP","R75",
    IF(LEFT(A1,3)="PNA","R100",
       IF(LEFT(A1,3)="PPC","R200",
          "R250"
          )
       )
    )



I believe you don't know how to evaluate a formula step by step. This is done in the "Formula" part of the main ribbon, "Formula auditing", "Evaluate formula". In the following screenshot, I pressed "Evaluate" one time, showing you how this feature works:


Incredible, this helps a lot. Thank you very much

@Brendon: You're welcome. If this answer helps you, please upvote it. In future, when other people have issues with Excel formulae, I might refer to this answer as a reference.
